# Is there a way to get a negative number with binary assignment without an overflowing_literals warning?

Tags: rust

Is there a way to get a negative number with binary assignment without the warning while preserving the other, more valid warnings. Or am I thinking about this wrong?

```
const NEG: i32 = 0b1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000;
// -2147483648
```

```
warning: literal out of range for i32
 --> src/main.rs:1:18
  |
1 | const NEG: i32 = 0b1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000;
  |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: #[warn(overflowing_literals)] on by default
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start with an unsigned type and then cast to a signed:

```
const NEG: i32 = 0b1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_u32 as i32;
```

> without the warning while preserving the other, more valid warnings

You can disable specific warnings for specific expressions:

```
#[allow(overflowing_literals)]
const NEG: i32 = 0b1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000;
```

However, this original behavior seems incorrect. The binary value is not out of range of an `i32`. [An issue seems to exist](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/48073).

Comment: Thank you. Glad to know that there's already an issue for this. Reading through the comments though, it would appear that the proponents of the warning are missing the point. I know what I'm doing, and I want to make a negative value...

Comment: But why? Why must I do all this knees bent running about when, if I'm using binary notation I might very well want a negative number?

Comment: @AaronH. I admit to being equally surprised. However, I have experienced that the people who work on Rust tend be be both smart and pragmatic, so I tend to give them a pretty large benefit of the doubt. I'm hoping this is a case where they see something that I just don't.

Answer (score 1):

You can place a `-` in front of it:

```
// warning
const N1: i32 = 0b1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000;

// no warning
const N2: i32 = -0b1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000;

assert_eq!(N1, N2);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8f852ec83794fbbc300e69c125b66848&version=stable)

However, your case is a special case, since `-N1 == N2`. Otherwise you have to negate one result of course (otherwise it would be super unintuitive).

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure that makes sense... If you're doing binary you know what you are doing?

Comment: Can you explain that? -N1 == N2? When I do:     println!("neg1 == neg2: {}", -NEG1 == NEG2);
I get: thread 'main' panicked at 'attempt to negate with overflow', src/main.rs:12:34

Comment: @AaronH.: `-N1` is `~N1 + 1` overflows right back to `N1` (but only for the literal)

Comment: Except that in Rust, the overflow panics in debug mode.

Comment: Except when using [`Wrapping`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/struct.Wrapping.html)

Answer (score 1):

> *Or am I thinking about this wrong?*

If all you want is the minimum and maximum `i32`, there's already `MIN` and `MAX` constants in the [`std::i32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/i32/) module. They're easier to understand, and you can't make a mistake.

```
use std::i32;

fn main() {
    const POS: i32 = i32::MAX;
    const NEG: i32 = i32::MIN;
    println!("{} {}", NEG, POS);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't want the min/max, I was just curious about the binary representation.